# TSQL - Average of all values in a column that are not zero

Tags: t-sql, average

I'm in the process of writing a report and am looking to get the average value of an age column. The problem is that not all rows have an age.

If the values for the column are 0 2 4 I would want 3 returned, not 2. I can not simply exclude the zero rows with a WHERE as I'm using using other columns in those rows. Is there such a thing as a AvgIfNotZero type of function?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT

    AVG (CASE WHEN Value <> 0 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
    ....
```

AVG won't take into account NULL values. Or this

```
    AVG (NULLIF(Value, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

,   (
        SELECT AVG(a) FROM

```
        (
        SELECT NULLIF([Column1], 0)
            UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULLIF([Column2], 0)
            UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULLIF([Column3], 0)
            UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULLIF([Column4], 0)
        ) T (a)
    ) AS [4 Column Average]
```

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.