# How to calculate the Average of fields that are not zero in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a few columns: Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5

i.e.

```
Week1 = 5
Week2 = 0
Week3 = 10
Week4 = 7
Week5 = 0
```

How do I calculate the average based on the fields that are not zero?

Incorrect:
(5+0+10+7+0)/5 = 4.4

Correct:
(5+0+10+7+0)/3 = 7.3

How to let create a custom column to let the SQL know that I only want to divide by 3 instead of 5?

Comment: You want to know how it can be done in T-SQL or a language?

Comment: T-SQL. i'm thinking of using AVG(CASE something) but not sure.

Comment: Are weeks1 2 etc columns? if yes, then AVG wont work...

Comment: More specifically, do you want, in 1 row, the average of the 5 columns Week1 - Week5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL - Average of all values in a column that are not zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751772/tsql-average-of-all-values-in-a-column-that-are-not-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one or more columns are not zero, then they are averaged as you expected.
To obtain a null when all are zero:

```
select (week1+week2+week3+week4+week5)/
  nullif(
    case when week1=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week2=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week3=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week4=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week5=0 then 0 else 1 end,
  0)
from ....
```

To obtain a zero when all are zero:

```
select 
  coalesce((week1+week2+week3+week4+week5)/
  nullif(
    case when week1=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week2=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week3=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week4=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when week5=0 then 0 else 1 end,
  0),0)
from ....
```

And if you want to be safe with null on columns:

```
select 
  coalesce((
    coalesce(week1,0) +
    coalesce(week2,0) +
    coalesce(week3,0) +
    coalesce(week4,0) +
    coalesce(week5,0) 
  )/
  nullif(
    case when coalesce(week1,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when coalesce(week2,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when coalesce(week3,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when coalesce(week4,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when coalesce(week5,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end,
  0),0)
from ....
```

Comment: Won't it result in a divide by zero overflow if all columns are 0?  You'd probably want to add a NULLIF(..., 0) to the bottom.

Comment: but if all columns are 0 it will then  result NULL. i think it's better to replace 0 with 1 to result 0.

Comment: @tjeloep, I'm not sure what is better to OP, so I give that option as an alternative on the answer

Comment: coalesce in each case?

Comment: is it possible to convert it to Access or do i have to create a separate question?

Comment: yes, to be clean, do a new question.  I give a hint here: you can replace nullif, coalesce and case when with `IIF` access function.

Answer (score 3):

As a note, these types of problems (aggregation within a row) are often more easily expressed using `apply`:

```
select a.average
from table t cross apply
     (select avg(nullif(val, 0)) as average
      from (values (t.week1),
                   (t.week2),
                   (t.week3),
                   (t.week4),
                   (t.week5)
           ) v(val)
     ) a;
```