# How to calculate avg in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an `AVG` of student scores in classic asp. Here is my student table:

```
Name   Q1   Q2
--------------
John   92   84
John   89   0
John   0    0
```

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Q1)/count(*) AS Q1, SUM(Q2)/count(*) AS Q2
FROM table Student
```

"0" should not be counted.

Q1 should be

```
92+89/2
```

or Q2 should be

```
84/1
```

However, the result for both always divide by `3`
How do I subtract 1 from any row that has `0`?

Comment: AVG function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Comment: See [tsql-average of all values in column that are not zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751772/tsql-average-of-all-values-in-a-column-that-are-not-zero)  and give credit where credit is due if answer helps!  The trick here is knowing null values aren't part of the count used in the denominator for calculating average!

Answer (score 13):

First of all, use `AVG` instead of `SUM` - it does all the work for you.

To ignore the zero scores in your situation (where you could have zero for Q1 and non-zero for Q2), use the [`NULLIF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to change the zeros to nulls. SQL will ignore the null values when calculating the average:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  AVG(NULLIF(Q1, 0)) AS Q1,
  AVG(NULLIF(Q2, 0)) AS Q2
FROM tableStudent;
```

The above query gives overall results for all students. If you want results by student you'll need to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  AVG(NULLIF(Q1, 0)) AS Q1,
  AVG(NULLIF(Q2, 0)) AS Q2
FROM tableStudent
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Q1 > 0 THEN Q1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Q1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q2 > 0 THEN Q2 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Q2
FROM table Student
```

Comment: I recomend to use Ed Gibbs answer!